# Is there a better way to solve this diagonalization?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Diagonalize the following matrix, if possible. You must show all work.

$$
\
  M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
    4 & 8 & 6 \\
    -4 & -6 & -3\\
    6 & 2 & 2\\
  \end{array} } \right]
\
$$

basically I have to find the coefficient equation, find the eigenvalues, find the eigenvectors, and put those eigenvectors as columns for P and find the inverse of P and then to $P^{-1}MP$ to find the diagonalized matrix right?

Comment: When you did your steps, what was your result?

Comment: Solution:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282669/diagonalize-matrix

Comment: @Somos if you make that tthe answer I'll give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, assuming you know how to find all of the eigenvalues and they are all distinct, then all you need to do is put them in the diagonal of a matrix, in any order. You don't need to find the
$P$ matrix unless it is a requirement for some reason. For example, the original matrix represents a linear map relative to some basis. The non-equivalent eigenvectors form another basis where the
representing matrix is diagonal. The matrix $P$ is the change of basis matrix between the original basis and the eigenvalues basis.
So, what you gave in your question is a correct method.